# npm: command not found - Gitlab CI specific runner

Tags: node.js, django, npm, continuous-integration, gitlab

I am running gitlab-runner on my server, I am not using docker for deployment. I am trying to achieve the deployment on a remote server by doing ssh to the server. This is my .gitlab-ci.yml file -

```
stages:
  - deploy

pre-staging:
  stage: deploy
  environment:
    name: Gitlab CI/CD for pre-staging deployment
    url: "$REMOTE_SERVER"
  before_script:
    - 'which ssh-agent || ( apt-get update -y && apt-get install openssh-client -y )'
    - mkdir -p ~/.ssh
    - eval $(ssh-agent -s)
    - 'echo -e "Host *\n\tStrictHostKeyChecking no\n\n" > ~/.ssh/config'
  script:
    - ssh-add <(echo "$REMOTE_PVT_KEY")
    - ssh ubuntu@"$REMOTE_SERVER" "cd deployment_container; npm --version ;rm -rf static; source deploy.sh"
    - echo "Deployment completed"
  only:
    - megre_requests
    - pre-staging
  tags:
    - auto-deploy
```

My pipeline is failing with error npm: command not found. I have proper environment for npm on my ssh-ed server. I am trying to deploy the Django-react application.
I have already tried using `image: node:latest`.
npm is installed using nvm

Can somebody help me resolve this?

Comment: "I have already tried using image: node:latest" but you're SSHing to a remote machine not running a docker image?

Comment: `megre_requests` appears to be spelled wrong. Does it still fail when that typo is fixed?

Comment: @nickclaw nope that is not the issue.

Comment: Instead ssh'ing one server from the other to execute pipeline why don't you install gitlab-runner on remote server and use this runner as your CI runner?

Answer (score 1):

Try and replace the ssh step with:

```
ssh ubuntu@"$REMOTE_SERVER" "pwd; cd deployment_container; echo $PATH"
```

If this "deployment" (which won't do anything) completes, it means `npm` is not accessible in the default `PATH` defined in the SSH session.

Answer (score 0):

In this we have to give npm access to all users by executing below command,

```
n=$(which node);n=${n%/bin/node}; chmod -R 755 $n/bin/*; sudo cp -r $n/{bin,lib,share} /usr/local
```

This resolved my issue of `npm: command not found`

Answer (score 0):

**You can try this one.**

```js
stages:
          - build
          - deploy

deploy-prod:
          image: node:12.13.0-alpine
          stage: deploy
          script:
            - npm i -g firebase-tools
```